Run a Linux command every 50 microseconds
I am very new to Linux in general, so apologies if this is a ridiculous question.
I would like to run a command line every 50 microseconds, I'm not sure if this is even possible.
I have tried to explore how quickly I can loop a simple command such as "echo Hello!", which I can only get to occur every 10E-3 seconds.
Does anyone have any advice?

What command is it?

In a shell (an interpreted language), probably not, although the sleep might let you specify sleep 0.00005. In a C program, maybe. Will the program you are starting every 50usec start, run, and finish before the next one starts? Can multiple copies cooperate or conflict?

Apology accepted.

echo is not even a simple command, in the sense of running an executable process. It is a shell built-in. I tried a tight shell loop (1000 iterations) on cat < /dev/null, and that comes in at 0.004 secs per iteration, so you are out by a factor of 80 already. What are you trying to achieve -- something small enough to run in 50 usec has to be very compact in C.

@waltinator sleep does take 2.7ms on my computer to start and to finish, plus the defined sleep time, and then plus the execution time of the other command, 50 mikro seconds .....,  if i want a fast clock instead of sleep i would use, read -t 0.00005, but read also takes 140mikro seconds on my computer to start plus defined time, mikro seconds .......

In my 57 year career (system&network programming&administration&security.) I've done Performance Analysis over and over, and learned: Don't use interpreted shells  - you can't control the overhead; Do "it" at least 1000 times (more is better, but time is finite); Be sure to know what you're timing - are you timing your shell's builtin echo or the program /bin/echo? Read man time, it's likely to help. Beware the difference between the shell builtin time and the program /usr/bin/time.

From the help center: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". What is the actual problem here? Beware of XY problem. Or do you want to run a command so frequently only for art's sake?
